# a program to alert when /var files system usage reaches threshold

Tags: linux, unix

I am working on a program which will send an snmp alert when /var reaches maximum threshold. I am having trouble with calculating % of /var disk usage for this.

I have this command "du -hs /var" which give me usage of /var in MB and /var is in the /root directory. So to calculate total disk on which /var is present I did the following command df -ks, this gives me the total of / and some % which I am not sure I should use. Can please someone help with a command for calculating the %.

Comment: Doesn't [the `df` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html) already *give* you the percentage?

Comment: yes it gives me %. What i was looking for is a proper formatted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
df /var | tail -1 | sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+%).*/\1/'
```

Breaking this down:

`df /var` outputs the header and one line for `/var`.

`tail -1` strips the header.

The `sed` command edits the line, capturing the percentage used and
discarding the rest. In words, we could say “match everything up to a
space, followed by one or more digits and a percent sign; capture the
digits and percent sign; match the rest of the line; replace the line
with the part that was captured”.

This produces a nice human-readable number with a percent sign. For
computing purposes you probably want the number *without* the percent
sign:

```
df /var | tail -1 | sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+)%.*/\1/'
```

Comment: I have a question: df /var gives me this output:   df /var
Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_mdm108-lv_root
                      94459756 7756860  81897880   9% /    Does this mean //dev/mapper/vg_mdm108-lvis mounted on   /var

Comment: That’s correct. The `/dev/mapper` string is a virtual filesystem provided by the logical volume manager. If you need to learn about that, I found this article to be an excellent introduction: https://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager .

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `snmpd` you would just need to add this to `snmpd.conf`:

```
disk /var 80%
```

This will generate a trap when the `/var` partition reaches 80% usage.

If you want to use the result of `df -k /var` command, use the `Use%` column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of snmpd.conf. I didn't know about it, and about the df -k /var command. I was looking for a formatted output.